# DB2 - Is there a way to get the list of tables a particular transaction has affected?

Tags: db2, db2-zos

We have a scenario where we would like to see if we could get hold of a list of tables affected by a given transaction. We use attunity to listen on the transaction log, but what I get from attunity is the transaction ID associated to a given event (a row change for a single table), not how many other tables that transaction has affected.

Consider the below update events -

```
UPDATE DEPARTMENTS SET (DEPT_NAME) = ('ChangedName3') WHERE DEPT_NO = 'd010';

UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET (FIRST_NME) = ('Georgi2') WHERE EMP_NO = '10001';

UPDATE DEPT_EMP SET (FROM_DTE) = ('1986-06-26') WHERE EMP_NO = '10001' AND DEPT_NO = 'd005';

UPDATE SALARIES SET (SALARY) = ('60111') WHERE EMP_NO = '10001' AND FROM_DTE = '1986-06-26';

UPDATE TITLES SET (TITLE) = ('Sr. Engineer') WHERE EMP_NO = '10001' AND FROM_DTE = '1986-06-26';

COMMIT;
```

This generates 5 events each having the transaction id - 00000000C420BC4E86DD010000000100 (I used a sample from attunity output).

Can I get something like -

00000000C420BC4E86DD010000000100, {EMPLOYEES, DEPARTMENTS, DEPT_EMP, SALARIES, TITLES} on each of the 5 events? Or query DB2 to find this information?

Comment: If you are on Db2 for LUW, an [event monitor for activities](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/t0059142.html) could do that.

Comment: @mustaccio - thanks for the reply, We are on z/os. I would still be interested in knowing how you would this on LUW. If you can provide some code example. I am not much of a DBA myself, trying to learn how the event monitor works.